# asp.net: How to open a new asp.net page in new window (not tab or current page) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page and I am trying to open a new one asp.net page on a button click in a new window as a popup and not in current or in a new tab.The method which the button click calls is :

```
private void OpenNewTranslationPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(),"OpenWindow","window.open('CreateProject.aspx','_newtab');",true);
}
```

I think that the _newtab is not proper, but I am wondering how it can it work.

Comment: Normally opening in a new tab is considered as popup by the browser and modern browsers tend to block it, therefore a better approach is to show the new link in a message to the end user, for example "Click <here> to go to new screen", <here> should be the link to new page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `_blank` property like

```
window.open('NLGCreateTranslationProject.aspx','_blank');
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

> To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special
>   value `_blank` for `strWindowName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
    protected void imgbtnPrint_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("window.open('ApprovalsByAccountPrint.aspx','_blank')");
        Response.Write("</script>"); 
    }
```

Comment: Here i am trying to do the same using an image click .You can do the same using button click.